# Autocomplete issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete

You can type in the field **Destination/Hotels** 
URL : http://think.thinkhotels.com/

It will auto suggest you. functionality is working fine. But when you press left/right arrow key then the cursor moves left/right as usual in **all browsers except chrome**.

I tried to modify code in the http://think.thinkhotels.com/autofill/jquery.autocomplete.js

It had a code

```
$input.bind(($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown") + ".autocomplete", function(event) {
        // a keypress means the input has focus
        // avoids issue where input had focus before the autocomplete was applied
        hasFocus = 1;
        // track last key pressed

        lastKeyPressCode = event.keyCode;
        switch(event.keyCode) {

            case KEY.UP:
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( select.visible() ) {
                    select.prev();
                } else {
                    onChange(0, true);
                }
                break;
```

I have added a few lines so that it avoids any action in left/right arrow below is the modified code

```
$input.bind(($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown") + ".autocomplete", function(event) {
        // a keypress means the input has focus
        // avoids issue where input had focus before the autocomplete was applied
        hasFocus = 1;
        // track last key pressed

         if(event.which ==KEY.LEFT  || event.which == KEY.RIGHT ) {
        return true;
        }

        lastKeyPressCode = event.keyCode;
        switch(event.keyCode) {

            case KEY.UP:
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( select.visible() ) {
                    select.prev();
                } else {
                    onChange(0, true);
                }
                break;
```

The Key is as follows

```
var KEY = {
        UP: 38,
        DOWN: 40,
        DEL: 46,
        TAB: 9,
        RETURN: 13,
        ESC: 27,
        COMMA: 188,
        PAGEUP: 33,
        PAGEDOWN: 34,
        BACKSPACE: 8,
        LEFT:   37,
        RIGHT:  39
    };
```

But the problem did not get fixed.
I have tried    return false; also that also didn't worked. I have tried event.preventDefault() that also didn't worked.

Can anyone find the solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete isn't the problem, it handles the left and right keys itself:

```
case KEY.LEFT:
case KEY.RIGHT:
  //Do nothing
  break;
```

The problem is you've got these attributes on the input field:

`onfocus="clearVal(), assignVal();" onchange="javascript: assignVal();" onblur="javascript: assignVal();" onclick="javascript: assignVal();" onkeypress="javascript: assignVal();" onkeyup="javascript: assignVal();"`

What's all that for? When I remove the `onkeypress` and `onkeyup` attributes it works fine. Here's the function that's being triggered:

```
function assignVal()
{
  var n=document.getElementById("city_t").value.split(" (");
  document.getElementById("city_t").value = n[0].replace(/\//g,"");
  document.getElementById("city").value = n[0].replace(/\//g,"");
  return true;
}
```

What this function is doing is the problem - you need to work out if this is necessary. If this is being used to "fix" something it's probably the wrong way to fix it.

Remove the function and all the attributes from the input and it'll work. If the functionality this function is attempting to provide is required for some reason, that's another question...